# Blocked Process Report SQL Server 31 hour duration

Tags: sql-server, profiler, blocking

I have an application (.NET EF 6 ) which is getting timeouts when submitting/reading data from the database. Whilst trying to diagnose the problem I used Blocked Process Reports from SQL server profile to see if I was getting any long blocks. I ran the trace and came across some peculiar very long blocks - 31 hour blocks. I want to know what these are and if I should be worried about them. I filtered the trace by Database name that I was concerned with.

example 1:

```
    <blocked-process-report>
 <blocked-process>
  <process id="process703b88" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 33:485576768:0 " waittime="115168485" ownerId="64139099452" transactionname="PurgeAllEmptyExtents2" lasttranstarted="2015-06-13T04:52:31.830" XDES="0x6b1731270" lockMode="X" schedulerid="6" kpid="4996" status="background" spid="10" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0">
   <executionStack/>
   <inputbuf>
   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </blocked-process>
 <blocking-process>
  <process status="sleeping" spid="444" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2015-06-14T12:51:46.637" lastbatchcompleted="2015-06-14T12:51:46.637" hostpid="5056" loginname="trend" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="63627468968" currentdb="33" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
   <executionStack/>
   <inputbuf>
FETCH API_CURSOR0000000000043F19   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </blocking-process>
</blocked-process-report>
```

Example 2:

```
<blocked-process-report>
 <blocked-process>
  <process id="process34a20f288" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 33:485576768:0 " waittime="107460436" ownerId="64211456029" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-06-13T07:00:07.107" XDES="0x1dc183340" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="4" kpid="6712" status="suspended" spid="58" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-06-13T07:01:00.090" lastbatchcompleted="2015-06-13T07:00:07.110" hostpid="5056" loginname="trend" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="64211456029" currentdb="33" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128058">
   <executionStack>
    <frame line="240" stmtstart="16612" stmtend="16774" sqlhandle="0x03002100f8128430bcc115016fa200000100000000000000"/>
    <frame line="1" sqlhandle="0x01002100f0e6ac0d90d6a500010000000000000000000000"/>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
exec sp_LogPurge &apos;2015-06-13 07:01:00&apos;;   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </blocked-process>
 <blocking-process>
  <process status="suspended" waitresource="OBJECT: 33:485576768:0 " waittime="114659439" spid="78" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-06-13T05:01:00.883" lastbatchcompleted="2015-06-13T05:00:59.767" hostpid="5056" loginname="trend" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="64144056143" currentdb="33" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128058">
   <executionStack>
    <frame line="240" stmtstart="16612" stmtend="16774" sqlhandle="0x03002100f8128430bcc115016fa200000100000000000000"/>
    <frame line="1" sqlhandle="0x0100210009260608307d4565030000000000000000000000"/>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
exec sp_LogPurge &apos;2015-06-13 05:01:00&apos;;   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </blocking-process>
</blocked-process-report>
```

The first one seems to be `FETCH API_CURSOR0000000000043F19` and the second one is some sort of log purge: `exec sp_LogPurge &apos;2015-06-13 05:01:00&apos;;`

What are these and should I be worired?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a huge fan of reporting profiler for checking blocking, but to get proper analysis would suggest you to either:

1) Use [Adam Mechanic's SP_WHOisActive](http://whoisactive.com) which is indeed very simple way of analyzing what and where could the blocking be a scenario with detailing on database name, app name along with its process.

2) If possible you can use [SqlDiag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162833(v=sql.105).aspx) utility to analyse same.

Ultimately, you need to find out who is doing the blocking first – why is their transaction taking so long? If it’s due to inefficiencies in the query – can you rewrite it? If it’s due to inefficiencies in the plan – can you add an index? If it’s modifying a large amount of data – can you break it down into smaller chunks so that each set is locked for a shorter period of time? These are ALWAYS the thing to try first.

However, if you still would like to go with reports to analyse blocking i would suggest to read [this article from Jonathan Kehayias](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Blocking/64474/) on how to use the block process report in sql server 2005/8

Comment: I'm using SP_WHOisActive at the moment, I have noticed various concerns with blocking on other databases within the SQL Server instance - namely the sp_LogPurge stored procedure - part of a 'off the shelf' product that we bought - I will be asking the manufacturer about that. I am trying to understand the results from the query related to the database I'm trying to improve. Question about SP_WHOisActive for you: is it a snapshot? I.e. is running it once going to actually help anything? Or would I have to get really lucky to run it at a intensive blocking period?

Comment: @user3585420, depends how you want to customize and use it. You can log the records in table for a duration you believe would be a good for troubleshooting. On how to do this would suggest you to read http://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are user processes and are part of an application, you can check the outer query for the cursor with the following

```
SELECT , c.session_id
       , c.properties
       , c.creation_time
       , c.is_open
       , t.text
FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors (0) c
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (c.sql_handle) t
```

and the text for the sp_LogPurge  with `SP_HELPTEXT sp_LogPurge` Your question is bit to generic as it is about application behavior without knowing anything about the application and if this is it's normal behavior or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help, when I run the query you suggested it returns no rows. What database am I supposed to run the `SP_HELPTEXT sp_LogPurge` query against? Thanks

Comment: The database you are monitoring. Skip the where condition on the query to get all the running cursors on the server

Comment: Hmm, the sp_LogPurge isn't on the database that I filtered by. When I remove the where condition I still get no results.

Comment: Check @kasqldba answer